# UISearchBar alignment issues in iOS 11

Tags: swift, ios11, uisearchcontroller

```
   I have UITableViewController where i was adding UISearchController searchbar as an headerView and I have changed this to navigationItem.searchcontroller for iOS 11 in iOS 11 searchbar won't appear at all even navigationItem was present.
```

if don't use this searchbar UI is going for toss. Please suggest me what was i am doing wrong here.

```
let  searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: vc)
            searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["All", "images", "videos", "others"]
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            // Don't remove these two lines then search bar alignment issue will raise
            self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
            self.searchController.searchBar.isHidden = false
            definesPresentationContext = false
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                 self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController // not working for me.
                searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
                 navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

            } else {
                searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
                searchController?.searchBar.sizeToFit()
                tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
            }
```

[image: searchbar]

List of issues are

- on iOS 11 with UI goes wrong as attached image if add UISearchbar to header view
- if I try add to navigation item as mentioned in the code it is not appearing
- As i am using different search results controller when search is active i need to disable actions in present controller - how can i achieve this easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what went wrong there but in my case, it's working fine. Here is my code:

1. Created a searchController file:

   ```
   private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
   ```
2. In `viewDidLoad()`:

   ```
   searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
   searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
   searchController.searchBar.placeholder = kSearchPlaceholder
   searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [kCategory, kAuthor, kPicture]
   searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
   definesPresentationContext = true

   if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     navigationItem.searchController = searchController
   } else {
     tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
   }
   ```

And it's good to go.